# Oracle 11g hextoraw sql query results

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I have a table called `mams_folder` , where primary key is `mams_folder_id`.

Now, its type is raw. I am representing keys in hexadecimal string.
Following queries were run on sql developer.

Now, I run these queries :

```
select * from mams_folder f where f.mams_folder_id= hextoraw('EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012'); //Works fine

select * from mams_folder f where f.mams_folder_id= 'EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012';//Surprisingly works fine too. Why ?

select * from mams_folder f where f.mams_folder_id= hextoraw('5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6'); //Works fine as expected

select * from mams_folder f where f.mams_folder_id= '5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6'; //Returns no rows as expected
```

Both are valid primary keys. `'5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6'` was newly inserted in database.

Why does db returns answer to second query but returns null for the last ?
Does it have to do something with db caching ?

**Update :**

Ok, I came to know that if I am using primary keys in uppercase hex string, then even without using hextoraw() , queries work fine (as we can see above). However when smaller case is used, hextoraw() becomes compulsary to use else empty result is shown. Why ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql and sql-server.  Don't spam-tag.

Comment: I assume Oracle performs an implicit cast from VARCHAR2 to RAW.

Comment: I'd assume the opposite to Wernfried and that the implicit cast is from the RAW column to VARCHAR2, and then the case-sensitivity of VARCHAR2 comparison comes into play. Plus it wouldn't be using an index. An EXPLAIN PLAN should indicate which way it is going.

Comment: @GaryMyers , you are right. Please see the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing stems from implicit/explicit type conversion mechanics when inserting by literal or hextoraw then later predicating against a literal.

Formal Hexadecimal is `0123456789ABCDEF` (uppercase), radix 16, though there is tooling (both in Oracle and elsewhere) to recognize character strings containing `0123456789abcdefABCDEF` (case insensitive) as hex.

`HEXTORAW` is case-insensitive and accepts lower-case hex.  But the returned `raw` value will be formal hex.

As an example, running the following:

```
SELECT HEXTORAW('5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6') AS HEX FROM DUAL;
```

Gives formal upper-case hex

```
HEX                               
5426DEAF924642BB9A38DC0B5BE87ED6
```

And the following will of course fail, as it contains a non-hex char `g`

```
SELECT HEXTORAW('5426geaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6') FROM DUAL;
ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

As will implicit conversion when inserting the above literal into a raw field.  RAW requires hex.

For the queries against `mams_folder` table, I believe the queries with lower-case literal predicates find no matches because when predicating with a string literal, the ensuing type conversion to compare `RAW` and `VARCHAR2` winds up attempting to match formal hex char against lower-case literal char.  (It does not convert the provided literal to `raw`, but compares the hex to the literal)

Since `HEXTORAW` converts any input string to formal hex in the conversion process, it ends up with a different comparison than the plain literal would anyway, even if it were comparing `char` instead of `raw`.

So the simple predicate that matches the converted (upper-case) `RAW` against a lower-case literal will result in no matches.  But when comparing an upper-case literal against the `RAW`, the formal hex used in comparison happens to match the upper-case string literal and the predicate is fulfilled.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE mams_folder (mams_folder_id RAW(32));
```

Then add the test data.  One item is added as an upper-case literal, one added as a lower-case literal, relying on oracle to do any needed  type conversion implicitly

```
INSERT INTO mams_folder VALUES ('EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012');
INSERT INTO mams_folder VALUES ('5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6');
```

Then just query to see how things look initially.  No `hextoraw` involved yet.

```
SELECT * FROM MAMS_FOLDER;

MAMS_FOLDER_ID                    
EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012  
5426DEAF924642BB9A38DC0B5BE87ED6
```

Note the printed value for the inserted literal `'5426deaf924642bb9a38dc0b5be87ed6'`.

Now the conversion comparing raw to upper-case literal matches.

In this query:

```
SELECT MAMS_FOLDER_ID, 'EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012' AS TARGET FROM MAMS_FOLDER;
```

We can see that the first row matches the converted raw with the literal.

```
MAMS_FOLDER_ID                    TARGET                            
EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012  EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012  
5426DEAF924642BB9A38DC0B5BE87ED6  EEA12100F39D100384D2080020F03012
```

With the implicit comparisons matching the formal hex from the `RAW` against the literal rather than converting the literal to a `raw`, `UPPER` would work just fine in a predicate as well.

```
SELECT * FROM MAMS_FOLDER F WHERE F.MAMS_FOLDER_ID = UPPER('5426DEAF924642BB9A38DC0B5BE87ED6');

MAMS_FOLDER_ID                    
5426DEAF924642BB9A38DC0B5BE87ED6
```